# Getting the value of td element in htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

```html
<td>
  <span>hi</span>
  <a>re</a>
  hello
</td>
```

I have DOM element structure as shown above.
Using htmlunit, i want to extract the value "hello" only, given that i have HtmlElement object referring to "td" node.
I tried using getTextContent(), but it returns "hirehello", which i dont want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, [`getTextContent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html?is-external=true#getTextContent()) clearly says it returns the text of the element *and* its descendants, and I don't see any other method to return just the sum of the text nodes, so I think you need a loop. E.g., assuming `element` refers to the `td` element:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(/*some appropriate size*/);
for (DomNode n : element.getChildNodes()) {
    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        sb.append(n.getTextContent());
    }
}
String text = sb.toString();
```

Note that the sum of the text nodes in the structure you've quoted *isn't* just `"hello"`, it'll have whitespace both before and after that. If you just want `"hello"`, you'll need to trim that off.

Comment: I guess `element.normalize()`, followed by `element.getLastChild().asText()` should do the trick, too. But I haven't tested it to make sure.

Comment: @JBNizet: Probably, for that *specific* structure, since in this specific case it's just the one text node they're interested in.